# How to Ref listen to AsyncNotifier in flutter riverpod

Tags: riverpod

So I am using the latest provider of riverpod and I want to listen on it, and these are my codes to listen

```
ref.listen<AccountManagementController>(
    accountManagementControllerProvider, (prev, next) {
      // if(next.hasError){

      // }
    });
```

however, I got some error or problem there it said

> The argument type 'AsyncNotifierProviderImpl<AccountManagementController, void>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ProviderListenable'

Answer (score 2):

I fix it , btw.

```
ref.listen<AsyncValue<void>>(accountManagementControllerProvider,
    (prev, next) {
  if (!next.isLoading && next.hasError) {
    _showErrorMessage(
      context,
      next.error.toString(),
      () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
  }
});
```